# Как выполнить скрипт установки сервиса на удаленном хосте используя Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible

Добрый день, дамы и господа! Я написал плейбук который копирует дистрибутив и инсталляционный скрипт на удаленный хост в директорию /tmp. Как с помощью Ansible выполнить этот скрипт с локальной машины? Насколько я понял, необходимо создать модуль к которому будет обращаться плэйбук. Путь к скрипту на удаленном хосте: /tmp/k-systemd/kafka/install.sh. Как, собсвенно, должен выглядеть модуль?

Благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно предварительно копировать скрипт.

Достаточно воспользоваться модулем [script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html):

```
- script: /some/local/create_file.sh --some-arguments 1234
```

Он самостоятельно возьмет скрипт (локально на машине с ansible), доставит на удаленный хост и запустит там.

Comment: дело всё в том, что у меня есть несколько виртуалок и на них необходимо развернуть zookeeper и kafka, я написал свой скрипт установки и положил рядом дистрибутив.
т.е. при выполнении копирования на удаленный хост, следом должен идти таск выполнения скрипта - script?

Comment: да. скрипт должен лежать где-то рядом с плейбуком. сначала закидываем дистрибутив на удаленную машину, затем просто модулем `script` говорим выполнить скрипт, который лежит локально рядом с плейбуком.

Comment: понял, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: в общем, я сделал всё в точности как вы писали выше
при выполнении скрипта возникает ошибка, мол, архив не найден, хотя всё лежит на своих местах, пути совпадают.

fatal: [k4-test-1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "failed": true, "rc": 1, "stderr": "", "stdout": "kafka archive file kafka_2.10-0.10.2.1.tgz not found\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["kafka archive file kafka_2.10-0.10.2.1.tgz not found"]}

Comment: если скрипт ожидает, что он запущен в той же папке, что и архив, то это не вариант – у модуля `script`, к сожалению, нет параметра `chdir`. В этом случае нужно все-таки предварительно скопировать его модулем `copy` и затем запустить модулем `command` или `shell` с указанием аргумента `chdir` на ту папку, где лежит архив.

Comment: эвоно как, благодарю за ценную информацию.